# Why does my Perl script using WWW-Mechanize fail intermittently?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to write a Perl script using WWW-Mechanize.
Here is my code:

```
use DBI;
use JSON;
use WWW::Mechanize;

sub fetch_companies_list
{
    my $url = shift;
    my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new( stack_depth => 0 );
    my ($content, $json, $parsed_text, $company_name, $company_url);
    eval
    {
        print "Getting the companies list...\n";
        $browser->get( $url );
#       die "Can't get the companies list.\n" unless( $browser->status );
        $content = $browser->content();
#       die "Can't get companies names.\n" unless( $browser->status );
        $json = new JSON;
        $parsed_text = $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode( $content );
        foreach(@$parsed_text)
        {
            $company_name = $_->{name};
            fetch_company_info( $company_name, $browser );
        }
    }
}

fetch_companies_list( "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/companies.js" );
```

The problem is the follows:

1. I start the script it finishes fine.
2. I restart the script. The script fails in "$browser->get()".

I have to wait some time (about 5 min) then it will start working again.

I am working on Linux and have WWW-Mechanize version 1.66.

Any idea what might be the problem? I don't have any firewall installed either on computer or on my router.
Moreover uncommenting the "die ..." line does not help as it stopping inside get() call. I can try to upgrade to the latest, which is 1.71, but I'd like to know if someone else experience this with this Perl module.

Comment: Is there a point in using `eval` if you're not inspecting `$@` afterwards?

Comment: @Tempus thank you!!! That was it. I added "warn $@ if $@ and put the "get()" call inside do...while(). After that everything works as expected. No more dying. BTW, is there a possibility to say thank you here and close the posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 minutes (300 seconds) is the default timeout. Exactly what timed out will be returned in the response's status line.

```
my $response = $mech->res;
if (!$response->is_success()) {
   die($response->status_line());
}
```

Comment: ikegami, what is the best way to handle such situation? Put this code in the loop? But then will it guarantee proper execution? Problem is I need to get the information from another page in the same script.... Besides I didn't time the script execution period, thats why I said "about"... Thank you.

Comment: @Igor, It's proper to check for the error after you do the operation that could result in the error, i.e. after you fetch the page.

Comment: ikegami, problem is that the code fails inside the get() call. And it does not come back from it to execute next statement - it dies. I will see if supplying "autocheck => 0" will continue the script. Thank you.

Comment: Just tried to supply "autocheck => 0" and uncomment first die() call. The script still dies silently inside $browser->get().

Comment: @Igor, you never mentioned any dying before. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is target site issue. It shows

> 503 Service Unavailable  No server is available to handle this
>   request.

right now.

Comment: yes, they have this problem. I hit it as well from time to time. Problem is how to gracefully handle it. I need this script to run flawlessly and not just die if such error occur but keep trying until everything is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Retry with wait, try this

```
## set maximum no of tries
my $retries = 10;
## number of secs to sleep
my $sleep = 1;
do {
    eval {
        print "Getting the companies list...\n";
        $browser->get($url);

        #       die "Can't get the companies list.\n" unless( $browser->status );
        $content = $browser->content();

        #       die "Can't get companies names.\n" unless( $browser->status );
        $json        = new JSON;
        $parsed_text = $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode($content);
        foreach (@$parsed_text) {
            $company_name = $_->{name};
            fetch_company_info( $company_name, $browser );
        }
    };

    if ($@) {
        warn $@;
        ## rest for some time
        sleep($sleep);
        ## increase the value of $sleep exponetially
        $sleep *= 2;
    }
} while ( $@ && $retries-- );
```